# Get list of installed programs and exclude the supporting programs

Tags: c#, wmi

We need to see list of installed programs from the remote machine for our internal audit. So I have created c# code. We need only the installed software. But we are getting around 450 items using the below code. Many of the items on the list are supporting software. We need to exclude the supporting files from the list

For example. If the visual studio is installed on the machine, the supporting files also listed. We need to exclude the supporting files from the list.

```
public List<ProductInfo> getlistofinstalledprograms(string IP,string username, string password)
    {
        List<ProductInfo> lstProductInfo = new List<ProductInfo>();

        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            options.Username = username;
            options.Password = password;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + IP + @"\root\cimv2", options);


            ObjectQuery objquery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
            ManagementObjectSearcher mobsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objquery);
            ProductInfo objProductInfo;

            foreach (ManagementObject mob in mobsearcher.Get())
            {

                objProductInfo = new ProductInfo();
                objProductInfo.ProductName = Convert.ToString(mob["Name"]);
                objProductInfo.ProductVersion = Convert.ToString(mob["Version"]);
                objProductInfo.Caption=Convert.ToString(mob["Caption"]);
                objProductInfo.Description=Convert.ToString(mob["Description"]);
                objProductInfo.ProductID=Convert.ToString(mob["ProductID"]);
                objProductInfo.RegCompany=Convert.ToString(mob["RegCompany"]);
                objProductInfo.RegOwner=Convert.ToString(mob["RegOwner"]);
                objProductInfo.SKUNumber=Convert.ToString(mob["SKUNumber"]);
                objProductInfo.Vendor=Convert.ToString(mob["Vendor"]);
                lstProductInfo.Add(objProductInfo);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return lstProductInfo;

    }
```

Could you help me to get the all installed programs excluding the supporting files

Comment: and what is "supporting software"?

Comment: Under the  control panel ->  Programs and Features, I could see 174 items. But I am getting 453 items when I execute the above code. I need only the 174 items listed on the control panel -> programs and features. So  I want to exclude the remaining 279 items.

Comment: The "Programs and Features" applet enumerates the values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, but even that does not correspond to the exact list. It's closer than what's produced by `Win32_Product`, though. However, even this list includes what you would call "support files" ("Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Policies" should probably not be considered its own product, for example, but it is listed as a separate entry on my machine).